# How to get material by line trace in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: graphics, unreal-engine4

I want to get the material of the static mesh using line trace, because the static mesh hold more than one material. I set complex line trace by chaanel, but the FHitResult does not return a rendering matrial, so I want to use FHitResult.FaceIndx to get the triangle's material. Is there any advice?

Comment: You have way more chances to  get your answer on unreal engine's forum  https://forums.unrealengine.com/

Comment: The amount of poeple following these tags is really low

Answer (score 1):

First do a sample raycast ,it hit a right object, the do a complex raycast and get the target mesh, int the complex raycast FHitResult, we get the FaceIndex, it means which triangle we hit. 
Then we can query the mesh use the FaceIndex, and get the Section ID(in UE4, the Section is unit of mesh, and one Scetion use one material, one Scetion can caontaions many triangles).
Last, get material id by section id.

```
FHitResult simpleResult = GetRaycastHitResultSimple(pc, startPos, endPos);
if (simpleResult.bBlockingHit)
{
    UStaticMeshComponent* staticMeshComponent = Cast<UStaticMeshComponent>(simpleResult.GetComponent());
    if (staticMeshComponent)
    {
        UStaticMesh* mesh = staticMeshComponent->StaticMesh;        
        if (mesh)
        {
            FHitResult complexResult = GetRaycastHitResultComplex(pc, startPos, endPos);

            return GetMaterialByFaceIndex(mesh, complexResult.FaceIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Get mesh from static mesh component faild"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cast FHitResul.GetComponent to static mesh component faild"));
    }
}
else
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Simple raycast faild"));
}


int32 UChangeMaterials::GetMaterialByFaceIndex(const UStaticMesh* mesh, const int32& faceIndex)
{
    const FStaticMeshLODResources& lodRes = mesh->GetLODForExport(0);
    int32 totalSection =  lodRes.Sections.Num();

    int32 totalFace = lodRes.GetNumTriangles();
    if (faceIndex > totalFace)
    {
        ///Wrong faceIndex.
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("GetMaterialbyFaceIndex Faild, Wrong faceIndex!"));
        return -1;
    }

    int32 totalTriangleIndex = 0;
    for (int32 sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < totalSection; ++sectionIndex)
    {
        FStaticMeshSection currentSection = lodRes.Sections[sectionIndex];
        /*Check for each triangle, so we can know which section our faceIndex in. For Low Performance, do not use it.
        for (int32 triangleIndex = totalTriangleIndex; triangleIndex < (int32)currentSection.NumTriangles + totalTriangleIndex; ++triangleIndex)
        {

            if (faceIndex == triangleIndex)
            {
                //return sectionIndex;
                return currentSection.MaterialIndex;
            }
        }
        totalTriangleIndex += lodRes.Sections[sectionIndex].NumTriangles;
        */

        ///the triangle index is sorted by section, the larger sectionIndex contains larger triangle index, so we can easily calculate which section the faceIndex in.Performance Well.
        int32 triangleIndex = totalTriangleIndex;
        if (faceIndex >= triangleIndex && faceIndex < triangleIndex + (int32)lodRes.Sections[sectionIndex].NumTriangles)
        {
            //return sectionIndex;
            return currentSection.MaterialIndex;
        }
        totalTriangleIndex += lodRes.Sections[sectionIndex].NumTriangles;
    }

    /// did not find the face in the mesh.
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("GetMaterialByFaceIndex, did not find it!"));
    return -2;
}
```